# It would be excellent experience for him

Tags: complements, subject-complement

> It would ***be excellent experience for him*** to travel a little.

> Clytemnestra ***is a pretentious name for a dog***.

(Reference: dictionary examples)

---

1. I wonder if ***excellent experience for him*** is a noun phrase and the complement of the verb ***be***.
2. I wonder if ***a pretentious name for a dog*** is a noun phrase and the complement of the verb ***is***.

Comment: Yes, that is a reasonable analysis. You can also analyze the relationship of the words *within* the phrases, but it's true that together they form the complement. Note that the first example is probably missing the word "an" after "be."

Comment: @AndyBonner The second example comes from here: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for. "Experience" seems to be used in the uncountable sense here

Comment: @Andy "*first example is probably missing the word "an" after "be."*" I disagree. If "experience" is being used in the sense of life expereicne or job experience, as in "to gain experience" then "an" should not be present. "an experience" is an event. "experience" is a property of a person, gained from events or actions. In this case, either sense is plausible, but the meaning is subtly different if 'an" is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both "excellent experience for him" and "a pretentious name for a dog" are noun phrases. Both are complements, but technically they are subject complements, not verb complements. Both follow linking verbs (in this case forms of "to be"). See ["Predicates, Objects, Complements"](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/objects.htm) from *Guide to Grammer* or ["What Are Complements? (with Examples)"](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/complement.htm) from Grammar Monster.

Comment: +1 for noting they're *subject* complements.